# Joomla Extra User Field

Tags: php, joomla1.5, user-input, html-input

I'm working with Joomla User Form. I need to create some extra fields. I googled, and got this [tutorial](http://manchumahara.com/2010/03/18/how-to-add-extra-fields-in-joomla-registration/)

I followed but that wasn't enough for me because I have to handle with checkbox and radio button. The following form code didn't save submission data (I mean checked/uncheked).

```
<input class="inputbox" type="checkbox" name="hasweb" id="hasweb" size="40" value="<?php echo $this->user->get('hasweb');?>" />
```

But the following is fine when I put any data there.

```
<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="hasweb" id="hasweb" size="40" value="<?php echo $this->user->get('hasweb');?>" />
```

I'm novice in Joomla. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the *value* and the *checked* state with HTML checkbox elements. So if you want to have the checkbox represent the actual choice you have to do something like this:

```
<input class="inputbox" type="checkbox" name="hasweb" id="hasweb" size="40" value="reallyhasweb" <?php echo $this->user->get('hasweb') == "reallyhasweb" ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>" />
```

This should place `checked="checked"` in the HTML when the user has selected the checkbox and will make the checkbox selected.

Comment: I don't have enough points to vote you up. So couldn't put an upvote for you. Really you solved my issue.
A bit correction, just need to remove **(** in front of **echo** ;).
Excellent.

Comment: You are right, there is one ( too much, fixed it. How about accepting my answer? You should be able to do this. Just click the tick beside my ansert. Thanks!